# How to implement bootstrap 4 tooltip in angular 4 application without using ngbTooltip?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody tell How to implement bootstrap 4 tooltip in angular 4 application without using `ngbTooltip`

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

am getting object doesn't support tool tip in angular 4 application. I have included bootstrap library

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple directive like this :

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
// Here we declare $ as variable to be able to use it after.
declare var $:any;

@Directive({
  selector:'[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Wait for Dom Element rendering, then elementRef represent DOM element from where Directive is bootstraped.
    $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).tooltip();
  }
}
```

then you can use it like this :

```
<p tooltip="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

[Online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlbklv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip.directive.ts)